# In itunes (for windows) can you set podcast location on disk to a different location?

Tags: itunes, windows

In itunes (latest for for windows) can you set podcast download location on disk to a different location that just the media folder set in preferences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, not really.  While you can specify the location of the entire iTunes Library folder (in **Preferences**, to to **Advanced**, and change the **iTunes Media** location), you can't set a different directory for specific types of media, such as podcasts.